# Filtering with jQuery -> applying changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a search box for data that is on the page of my site.  Basically, I load a bunch of tables/lists and want to have a filtering input.

This is the JS:

```
$('#search-term').keyup(function(event) {

    var query = event.target.value;
    var selector = "ul:contains(" + query + ")";

    $('ul').not(selector).hide();

});
```

The problem is that the search-term changes but the lists that don't match the result stay hidden.  In other words, once I type out of the first time, those elements stay hidden.

Question: So how can I have the selector update to match the result of the changing query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show by default, then hide like

```
$('#search-term').keyup(function(event) {
    $('ul').show();

    var query = event.target.value;
    var selector = "ul:contains(" + query + ")";

    $('ul').not(selector).hide();

});
```

Comment: Wow, I kept thinking of it the opposite way and didn't want to hide the data first. Thanks - works perfectly.